# $X_{t} - X_{s}$ independent of $\mathcal{F}^{X}_{s}$ for $0 \leq s < t$.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, self-learning

I'm trying to prove that $X_{t} - X_{s}$ independent of $\mathcal{F}^{X}_{s}$ for $0 \leq s < t$, but I have a hard time getting started. My idea was to use expectations but I'm not quite convinced that I'm on the right path.

The problem is as follows. Assume the usual probability space.

- We have a random process $(X_{t})_{t\in \mathbb{R}_{+}}$ with independent increments.
- We have that the natural filtration is given by $\mathcal{F}_{t}^{X} = \sigma(\{X_{s}:0 \leq s < t\})$ for $t < \infty$ and $\mathcal{F}_{t}^{X} = \sigma(\{X_{s}:s \in \mathbb{R}_{+}\})$ for $t = \infty$.

I want now to prove that $X_{t} - X_{s}$ independent of $\mathcal{F}^{X}_{s}$ for $0 \leq s < t$.

Can someone explain me how to do so.

Answer (score 2):

I think this holds only when $X_0$ is deterministic.

By definition, $(X_t)_{t\in\mathbb R}$ has [independent increments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_increments) iff for any $m\in\mathbb N$ and any choice $t_0<t_1<...<t_m$ the variables
$$
(X_{t_1}-X_{t_0}),...,(X_{t_m}-X_{t_{m-1}})
$$
are stochastically independent.

Let $0\le s<t$ and take $t_m=t,t_{m-1}=s\,.$ Then $X_t-X_s$ is independent of
$$
(X_{t_1}-X_{t_0})+...+(X_{t_{m-2}}-X_{t_{m-3}})=X_{t_{m-2}}-X_{t_0}\,.
$$
Since $t_{m-2}<s$ is arbitrary and $t_0$ can be $0$ it follows from the assumption that $X_0$ is determinisic that $X_t-X_s$ is independent of any $X_{t_{m-2}}$ with $t_{m-2}<s\,.$
In other words, $X_t-X_s$ is independent of ${\cal F}^X_s\,.$

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you a lot. I’m wondering what the argument would be that this wouldn’t work for a stochastic $X_{0}$? Regarding that $X_{0}$ is deterministic are we implicitly assuming that is is equal to 0 almost surely?

Comment: Regarding your last question : $1$ is deterministic and different from $0$ as far as I can tell. Does this give a hint what we are assuming ?  Regarding the stochastic $X_0$: some authors (e.g. Heinz Bauer) define independent increments slightly differently: $X_0,(X_{t_1}-X_{t_0}),...,(X_{t_m}-X_{t_{m-1}})$ are independent (the stochastic $X_0$ is included in that list). Can you deduce the independence of $X_t-X_s$ from $X_{t_{m-2}}$ from that stronger assumption? Let me know if you can't.

Comment: I see that I’ve made a mistake. It should be a $0 \leq s \leq t$ instead of $0 \leq s < t$ where I defined $\mathcal{F}^{X}_{t}$ for $t<\infty$. Regarding your first answer it’s clear that $1$ is deteterministic and different from $0$ but I’m not sure what what we are assuming with that. Regarding the second I understand your point but I didn’t think it was a stronger assumption to have $X_{t_{1}}-X_{t_{0}}$ included.